# how can i stop an object when touched by another

Tags: unity-game-engine

I I have a 2D object with a collision, which I move with the mouse through velocity, when it comes into contact with the same object, it moves another object. How can you make sure that he does not move it, but when you click on it, you can also move it?
I tried to do so:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "GameController")
        { 
            collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
            collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().angularVelocity = 0f;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The physics engine (PhysX) was not built to handle this sort of behavior. You're going to have to knuckle down and do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just enable the [`isKinematic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-isKinematic.html) part of the respective game-objects which you want to control it's movement, but won't be affected by others.

[This](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/154901/dynamic-vs-kinematic-do-either-of-these-cause-a-collision-before-oncollisionent) post gives a good explanation on why setting the kinematic property can solve your issue.

Comment: but with kinematics it passes through objects

Comment: @ArtemVolkov You might need to specify more context on what you want this to be used for; Ultimately, stuff like solid walls/obstacles should be kinematic. Depending on the context you give, we might need to implement a solution ourselves

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the mouse to control the movement, you should add the boolen variable to the moving logic. When CollisionEnter is triggered, the movement logic is not executed.